# Using VBA SQL to find multiple records based on list box selection

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a form with a listbox containing various products and a combobox which is supposed to contain one or more process numbers (the same product can have more than one process number) when a product is selected from the list box. The process numbers are contained in another table (Process Order) and I've been playing around with SQL to try and figure it out but it keeps coming up with syntax error or tells me I have a missing operator.

The code below is something I tried based on another example I found on here but this is my first time using SQL.

```
Dim strMyString As Variant

'lstProduct is the listbox containing the products
strMyString = lstProduct.Value

'Process Order is the table name, Process No the field containing the Process Numbers and Product Description is the field I want to match the listbox value
strSQL = "SELECT [Process Order].[Process No] FROM [Process Order] WHERE [Product Description]= '" & strMyString

'cmbProcNo is the combobox where I want the process numbers to be displayed
cmbProcNo.RowSource = strMyString
```

Apologies if this is a silly question but any help is really appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: You are missing adding an ending `'` after `strMyString`

Comment: Thanks, it gets past that part now but how do I get the combobox to display the values the query finds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct code !

```
Dim strSQL As String

'lstProduct is the listbox containing the products'

'Process Order is the table name, Process No the field containing the Process Numbers and Product Description is the field I want to match the listbox value'
strSQL = "SELECT [Process Order].[Process No] FROM [Process Order] WHERE [Product Description]= '" & Me.lstProduct & "'"

'cmbProcNo is the combobox where I want the process numbers to be displayed'
Me.cmbProcNo.RowSource = strSQL
Me.cmbProcNo.Requery
```

You forgot to close the SQL statement. Then you need to assign the SQL to the ComboBox rowsource not the value of the Listbox.

Comment: Most welcome, feel free to mark it as answer so other may also be benefited by this. Good luck.